# How to enable shift key - multi selection in prime ng pick list?

Tags: angular, multi-select, primeng, shift

I am using prime ng pick list from prime ng api : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist

One of the issues that I am facing here is that picklist does not support multi selection .

Example of multi selection : http://jsfiddle.net/bMgpc/170/

In the fiddle , the code given is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').multiSelect({
        unselectOn: 'body',
        keepSelection: false,
    });
});
```

How do I enable multi select using shift key where in I can perform a range selection ?

Any help is greatly appreciated ...

Comment: if you can enable multi select using shift key, inprove the code. Just in the function onItemClick, check if shith key is pressed and save in two variables the index. If you have two index, select all the items between this index

Comment: @Eliseo  Not that I am against improving the code , just that what I am working on currently is very time sensitive .. So either I get to use picklist or fall back on some other plugin to get to where I want to .

Answer (score 0):

First, using JQuery with Angular is an anti-pattern. So avoid this and don't use the solution provided by this fiddle.

Second, from the documentation :

> ## Multiple Selection
>
> Multiple items can either be selected using metaKey or toggled individually depending on the value of metaKeySelection property value which is true by default. On touch enabled devices metaKeySelection is turned off automatically.

Apparently the multiple selection is enabled by default.

You're not succeeding because the metakey is actually Ctrl, not Shift :)

You also can use `[metaKeySelection]="false"` to allow your users to directly click on the items to select them, witht the need of the metakey (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: 1> Yes .. I am aware of the fact that jquery should not be used . I have provided the jquery example to let the onlookers understand what I am talking about .
2> I am also aware of the fact that the meta key here refers to CTRL-Key and not shift . That's why I have asked the question to know whether there is a way of using shift multi select here .

Comment: Well then, you sohuld have been more specific in your question ! I don't think you can do it natively. But you probably can write some logic around the `onSourceSelect` event : get the mouse event (to know if shift is pressed), get the last selected item, if shift is pressed, select all items from the previously selected item to the newly selected item. If you can provide a sandbox of primeng, I could try to do this with you !